# How to delete Row when 'AllowUserToDeleteRows' is set to $True?

Tags: powershell, winforms, datagridview

I have an empty DataGridView for Users to add new entries to a table in an SQL database. To fit the needs of the user they should be able to add rows to the datagridview and delete rows according to the amount of rows they want to add.

I have set both `AllowUserToAddRows` and `AllowUserToDeleteRows` to `$True` but only adding rows is working. When I reach the last row of the 4 predefined rows it creates a 5th row but when I delete the data from the 5th and 4th rows and try to delete the row with DEL/BACKSPACE or any other method I could think of it won't disappear. If I click the rowheader it scrolls down and for a second you think it deleted the row but it's still there

Here's my code. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#Datasource2 - DGV2
$script:AWtable2 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
$script:AWAddColumnNames2 = $script:AWtable1.Columns.ColumnName | ForEach-Object {$AWnewcol2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn $_,([string]); $script:AWtable2.columns.add($AWnewcol2)};
#Add empty rows
for($i=0;$i -le 2;$i=$i+1){
    $script:NewRow1 = $script:AWtable2.NewRow()
    $script:AWtable2.Rows.Add($script:NewRow1)
}

#DataGridView2
$script:dataGridView2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView;
$script:dataGridView2.Name = 'dataGridView2';
$script:dataGridView2.Size = '1235, 132';
$script:dataGridView2.Location = '13, 21';
$script:dataGridView2.Anchor = (4, 8, 1);
$script:dataGridView2.TabIndex = 4;
$script:dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 2;
$script:dataGridView2.RowHeadersVisible = $True;
$script:dataGridView2.RowHeadersWidth = 24;
$script:dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = $True;
$script:dataGridView2.AllowUserToDeleteRows = $True;
$script:dataGridView2.AllowUserToOrderColumns = $False;
$script:dataGridView2.AllowUserToResizeRows = $False;
$script:dataGridView2.DataSource = $script:AWtable2;
$script:dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = $false;
$script:dataGridView2.EditMode = 0;

#Manually create Columns
$script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Col0", "Col0") | Out-Null
#[...]
$script:dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Col17", "Col17") | Out-Null

#Column Width and Visibility
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[0].Visible = 0;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[1].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[2].Visible = 0;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[3].Visible = 0;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[4].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width + $script:dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[5].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[7].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[7].Width;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[8].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[8].Width;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[10].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[10].Width;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[11].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[11].Width;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[14].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[14].Width;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[15].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[15].Width;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[16].Width = $script:dataGridView1.Columns[16].Width;

#AutoSizeMode
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[6].AutoSizeMode = 2;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[9].AutoSizeMode = 4;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[12].AutoSizeMode = 4;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[13].AutoSizeMode = 2;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[14].AutoSizeMode = 1;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[15].AutoSizeMode = 1;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[16].AutoSizeMode = 1;
$script:dataGridView2.Columns[17].AutoSizeMode = 16;

#Workaround to allow resizing
for($i=0; $i -le $script:dataGridView2.Columns.Count - 1; $i=$i+1){
    $script:colw2 = $script:dataGridView2.Columns[$i].Width;
    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[$i].AutoSizeMode = 1;
    $script:dataGridView2.Columns[$i].Width = $script:colw2;
}
```

Comment: DGV when set to AllowUserToAddRow will always have a blank row at the bottom which is used to add new rows.  So you should always have one empty row at the bottom.